# How do you easily check whether a Variable is number or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, typeof, isnan

I am not a JavaScript developer, but I just want to know the right way to check a variable contain a number or not. After a couple analysis I reached below solution. Is it correct way?

```js
function calculation(n1,n2 , ...numbers) {

  let validateNumber = (num) => {
    if(num !== num)
      return 0;
      else
    return typeof num === 'number' ? num : 0;
  }

  let sum =0;
  for(n of numbers){
    sum += validateNumber(n);
  }
  console.log(sum);
} 

calculation(5,6,7,'gg','',null, NaN, undefined,  null,8,9,5.4,10);
```

Please check the 'validateNumber' arrow function.

Comment: why arguments `n1,n2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First version =>
-- simply use `isNaN()`  : `sum+(isNaN(val)?0:Number(val)`

Second version (asked in comment here) =>
-- just use a strict comparison. to get only numeric type values.

```js
const calculation =(...numbers)=>  // (n1,n2 , ...numbers)=>
  numbers.reduce((sum,val)=>
    sum + (Number(val)===val ? val : 0)  // sum+(isNaN(val)?0:Number(val))
    , 0);

console.log( calculation(5,6,7,'gg','',null, NaN, undefined,  null,8,9,5.4,'10') )
```

> For more clarity, here it is a table showing the execution of the test according to the different possible types

```js
const
  testFunction = val => Number(val)===val
, values =
  [ { v: 123,       display: `123`,       expected: true  }
  , { v: '123',     display: `"123"`,     expected: false }
  , { v: NaN,       display: `NaN`,       expected: false }
  , { v: undefined, display: `undefined`, expected: false }
  , { v: null,      display: `null`,      expected: false }
  ]
, tBody = document.querySelector('table > tbody')
  ;
let score = 0
  ;
for (let {v, display, expected} of values)
  {
  let
    TR  = tBody.insertRow()
  , res = testFunction(v)
    ;
  score += expected===res ? 1 : 0
  TR.insertCell().textContent = display
  TR.insertCell().textContent = expected
  TR.insertCell().textContent = res
  TR.insertCell().className   = expected===res ? 'ok' : 'bad'
  }
document.querySelector('table >tfoot td:nth-of-type(2)')
  .textContent = `${score} / ${values.length}`
```

```css
table { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0 1em; }
td    { padding: .2em .8em;border: 1px solid darkblue; } 
thead,tfoot {  background-color: #84a4ce;text-transform: capitalize; }
caption     { padding: .3em;caption-side: bottom;font-size: .8em; }
.ok:before,.bad:before { font-weight: bold;font-size: 1.2em; }
.ok:before  { color: green;content: '\2713'; }
.bad:before { color: red;  content: '\2718'; }
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>( Number(val)===val ) ?</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr> <td>val</td><td>expected</td><td colspan="2">result</td> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr> <td colspan="3">score</td><td>0/0</td> </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: @Andy because there are the 2 arguments n1 and n2 before

Comment: @Jojo don't mid the calculation part it is only for testing purpose . I am looking for  easy and alternative condition  in  'validateNumber ' .

Comment: @Jojo Sorry for the complexity . the code snippet is part of my learning activity . I was looking into the Rest parameter concept , so the additional parameters n1 and n2 :) . Any way my doubt is regarding alternative approaches for  verifying a given value is number or not .

Comment: @Jojo :) I am looking for better approach for  verifying a given value is number or not. Please stick to the point. I don't prefer to use  isNaN() .

Comment: @Jojo Your code sample fails at this point  calculation(5,6,7,'gg','',null, NaN, undefined,  null,8,9,5.4,'10'); . It still generate same output . Please show some respect to my question. isNaN() cause a type conversion.

Comment: @DeepakKoshy I added a table allowing to see the results of this function in correspondence with the different possible types (see 2th snippet while opened)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is built in function in JavaScript to check if a certain value is number or not which is [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

If you want to get the sum of all the numbers in the array then you can try using `reduce()` like the following way:

```js
var data = [5,6,7,'gg','',null, NaN, undefined,  null,8,9,5.4,10];
var sum = data.reduce((a,c) =>{
  if(!isNaN(c)){
    a = a + Number(c); //convert the '' and null to 0 with Number()
  }
  
  return a;
},0);
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a one liner also

```
export const isNum = n => Number(n) === Number(n);
```

First parse to number what Eva param you get them compare to itself.
One of them `what the hell's` that comes with JavaScript is that `NaN !== NaN` so if the value you get after forcing it to be a number become s a Nan it will be different from itself

Comment: In yow case all you need to do there is to  change it validateNumber func with my isNum

Comment: it is always `true`, you mean `const isNum = n => Number(n) === n;`

Answer (score 0):

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the elements that aren't numbers by checking to see if they're not `null` and also a number, and then using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum up the elements.

```js
function calculation(n1, n2, ...elements) {
  
  return elements

    // `filter` out the elements that are numbers
    .filter(el => el && Number(el))

    // Add them all up
    .reduce((acc, c) => acc + c, 0);
}

console.log(calculation(5,6,7,'gg','',null, NaN, undefined,  null,8,9,5.4,10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return n === Number(n);
}
```